# React : Get states of an input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using [react-intl-tel-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intl-tel-input) for **react** to create an input with countries.

The **change** for the values occurs for both the input and the country, but I can't find where the state is saved, as I would want to send them to my database later.

**I tried creating my own `handleChange` but it didn't turn out as I wanted. Any ideas about how to get or set the states ?**

Code ( Comments are what I tried ):

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-keldysh-h32qh?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import IntlTelInput from "react-intl-tel-input";
import "react-intl-tel-input/dist/main.css";

export default function App() {
  // const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  // const handleChange = (event) => {
  //   setInput(event.target.value);
  //   console.log(event);
  //  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <IntlTelInput
        containerClassName="intl-tel-input"
        inputClassName="form-control"
        preferredCountries={["tw"]}
        //onchange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: https://patw0929.github.io/react-intl-tel-input/?selectedKind=Documentation&selectedStory=Props&full=0&addons=0&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybooks%2Fstorybook-addon-knobs

Please read the docs thoroughly before asking questions thank you.

Comment: @Hadi Pawar I agree with you for the value of the input, I didn't see it. What about the country selection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import IntlTelInput from "react-intl-tel-input";
import "react-intl-tel-input/dist/main.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <IntlTelInput
        containerClassName="intl-tel-input"
        inputClassName="form-control"
        preferredCountries={["tw"]}
        customPlaceholder={(num, country) => {
          console.log(country.name, country.dialCode, country.areaCodes);
        }}
        onPhoneNumberChange={(b, n, c, number) => {
          console.log(number);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

- Official docs [link](https://patw0929.github.io/react-intl-tel-input/?selectedKind=Documentation&selectedStory=Props&full=0&addons=0&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybooks%2Fstorybook-addon-knobs)
- [Link](https://patw0929.github.io/react-intl-tel-input/?selectedKind=Documentation&selectedStory=Playground&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel) to official **playground** to test all props in realtime without coding

The 3rd argument in the onPhoneNumberChange prop marked as `c` in my code will also give you country details. The reason I did not choose the country code from here is when a user selects a flag at the end after inputting the number the country details are not captured in this onPhoneNumberChange prop.

Comment: This is working ! But I have one question, as I want to pass those info to the database, where can I find the state ? I see you put ` {(num, country)}` but I have no idea where did you came with that. Also I did `onSelectFlag={(num, country) => {console.log(country.iso2);
}}` instead so I have the code of every selected country.

Comment: @AlyaKra if you click the playground link I provided and you just select a country you will see all props with the inputs they receive. Example `customPlaceholder: ["", Object]
0: ""
1: Object
areaCodes: null
dialCode: "1"
iso2: "us"
name: "United States"
priority: 0` So from here you understand that customPlaceholder prop takes 2 arguments, the first one is a string and the second one is an object with key areaCodes, dialCode, ISO2, name, priority

Comment: Yes I saw that. But from where did you come up with country ? There is nothing mentionned in the array about it. Is that the one you initialized ?

Comment: Well for example in customPlaceholder prop the first argument is a string I named it num and you can name it anything you want like number or n it doesn't matter. Likewise the 2nd argument is the object and I just named it country. You can name it freedom it you want :)

Comment: So this code is perfect and will also work `customPlaceholder={(num, freedom) => {
          console.log(freedom.name, freedom.dialCode, freedom.areaCodes);
        }}`

Comment: I see. Thank you very very much I was really struggling. One last thing, how can I pass that data let say `country.iso2` to my database? I don't have a state that I can send to my database ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231887/discussion-between-subha-and-alyakra).

Answer (score 0):

Accourding to [docs](https://patw0929.github.io/react-intl-tel-input/?selectedKind=Documentation&selectedStory=Props&full=0&addons=0&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybooks%2Fstorybook-addon-knobs),

> `onPhoneNumberChange` -> Optional validation callback function. It returns validation status, input box value and selected country data.

> `onSelectFlag` -> Allow main app to do things when a country is selected.

Here is example [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/yml35835j1)

Comment: `onSelectFlag` displays an array, how can I get a specific element for example name ?